# Suggestion for a "merge of structures"

Tags: java, linked-list, binary-search-tree

My professor ask me to do a "merge of structures" that we already studied. How is that? Like a Max/Min heap using a doubly linked list instead of an array for example. But I cannot think of any structure that I can improve (make some method faster "merging structures"). Can anyone give me a tip? Or some link that can help me?

Ps: Until now I already studied*: LinkedList(Single and Doubly), Binary Heap, BST and Skip lists.

Ps1: Sorry for my English - it is not my first language.

- : I studied more, but he already asked to do other structures (Stack using linkedlist for example).

Comment: Can you specify what exactly do you want, merge of structures is not making much sense

Comment: Sorry. Let's say: Generally when you construct an Max Heap you will use an array, right? But if you choice create a Max Heap using a doubly linked list? My alghorithm will be faster? I will have some advantage in any method(insert, search)? This is what i need to do. Create an new aproach for these structures(LinkedList, Binary Heap(Max or Min) or Skip Lists).

Comment: Have you studied hash tables?

Comment: Not yet. x.x. What i studied until now: Queue, Stack*, LinkedList, BST, Heap and Skip Lists. Not much things yet. Ps: We already did some things with Queue and Stack.

Comment: Why not create a doubly linked skip list? Note that *improving* does not always mean making it perform any better. Addition functionality is often just as important.

Comment: How is that? Can you explain more? Anyway, thanks for the tip. Edit: Explain this part: "Note that improving does not always mean making it perform any better. Addition functionality is often just as important"

Comment: In computer science merge structures usually means to combine two or more similar structures into an aggregate with a similar structure such as when merging two lists into one bigger list.  So for example, the same might be done for two heaps by combining them into one heap and similarly for two stacks, queues, etc., the problem being to define precisely what merge means and how its done for each case.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedLists are a good choice for a 2nd data structure merged into another.

Java has a LinkedHashMap that is a merge of two data structures, the Map and the LinkedList.  The LinkedList component can maintain an insert order or an LRU order for an LRU cache.